# Unity hover documentation for Start(), Update(), etc. in VSCode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

How can I get hover documentation for `Start()`, `Awake()`, `Update()`, etc. to show up for Unity C# in VSCode

Here is what it looks like in visual studio:

[image]

> void Player.Start()
>
> Unity: Start is called just before any of the Update methods is called the first time

And here is it in VSCode:

[image]

> void Player.Start()

The hover documentation is working for classes and other functions in VSCode (after following [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity)),

[image]

just not these ones you implement yourself.