# Unity hover documentation in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to use Visual Studio Code as my editor for c # code in Unity and I want to hover over the code to display a short description of what, for example, the method does.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68969085/unity-hover-documentation-for-start-update-etc-in-vscode) thread but I don't know what to do exactly.

Does anyone know how to do it and is it such an option?

P.S.:
And by the way, does anyone know a good extension with syntax highlighting?

Comment: Vscode is not visual studio. You can’t expect the same

Comment: I would just recommend to use Visual Studio for C# esspecially with Unity. If you do not want this there is a tutorial linked how to achive what u want in VSC just in the thread you shared.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answers. 
If someone does it somehow, please write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found something like an answer. I didn't think this would change anything, but I downloaded the [Windows: .NET Framework 4.7.1 Developer Pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net471) as this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) says and the syntax started to stand out and I get a little hint as I hover over the methods.